# How to automatically refresh a webpage, expand a + menu, and scroll down to that menu?

Tags: automation, data-science

I'm tracking the daily COVID cases reported on this webpage: https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#trends_dailytrendscases.
The website updates the daily case count once a day by creating a new row in the "Data Table for Daily Case Trends - United States" table. The table entries are only viewable by clicking the + symbol.

My method of checking for updates is to manually refresh the webpage, scroll down to the menu, and click the + symbol. I'd like to automate this process to save myself from repeating this process constantly.

I'm not a web developer, so I'd prefer to use a browser extension or something simple if possible. I can code a little bit if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you could use Python with e.g. BeautifulSoup to automate that.
But you could also use https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/rpa/

Which leads to code like this in that addon:

```
{
  "Name": "Data",
  "CreationDate": "2021-8-5",
  "Commands": [
    {
      "Command": "open",
      "Target": "https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#trends_dailytrendscases",
      "Value": "",
      "Description": ""
    },
    {
      "Command": "click",
      "Target": "id=us-trends-table-header-icon",
      "Value": "",
      "Targets": [
        "id=us-trends-table-header-icon",
        "xpath=//*[@id=\"us-trends-table-header-icon\"]",
        "xpath=//i[@id='us-trends-table-header-icon']",
        "xpath=//div[5]/div/div/i",
        "css=#us-trends-table-header-icon"
      ],
      "Description": ""
    },
    {
      "Command": "click",
      "Target": "id=btnUSTrendsTableExport",
      "Value": "",
      "Targets": [
        "id=btnUSTrendsTableExport",
        "xpath=//*[@id=\"btnUSTrendsTableExport\"]",
        "xpath=//button[@id='btnUSTrendsTableExport']",
        "xpath=//div[5]/div[2]/div/button",
        "css=#btnUSTrendsTableExport"
      ],
      "Description": ""
    },
    {
      "Command": "click",
      "Target": "xpath=/html/body/a",
      "Value": "",
      "Targets": [
        "xpath=/html/body/a",
        "xpath=//body/a",
        "css=body > a"
      ],
      "Description": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

This code will save the complete data as csv file.

Does this help you out?
It is a little script with Python and Selenium.
But you'll need to setup a little dev-environment.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import re
import time
import datetime

url = "https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#trends_dailytrendscases"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'd:\Python-Buch\RealPython\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

try:
    driver.maximize_window()
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, 'us-trends-table-toggle')))
    time.sleep(2)
    update = driver.execute_script("return $('.general_note').text()")
    day = re.findall('Data as of:\s+\w+,\s+\w+\s+(\d+)', update)
    today = datetime.datetime.today().day

    print('---')
    print('Upload string:', update)
    print('Day of data:', day)
    print('Today:', today)

    if int(day[0]) == today:
        print('NEW DATA')
    else:
        print('OLD DATA')

    print('---')
    
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: This looks very helpful, does this extension have a way to keep checking until the newest data row appears and then create an alert once it happens?

Comment: Yes, this should be possible with variables. Maybe all you need is another plugin. Have a look at https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/distill-web-monitor-ff/

Comment: Yes distill was the first thing I tried. Unfortunately it produced many false positives and more importantly, false negative. Is there a recommended tutorial for dummies on how to use variables in the rpa extension to keep checking and be alerted of change?

Comment: What does your complete process look like? What are you really doing? Can you describe that in more detail? Then I could write probaly write the code for you. 1) Check if there is new data then what? Does the process need to be a loop?

Comment: The exact steps I'm looking to execute are - 1 webpage automatically refreshes every so often (5 minutes?), 2 webpage scrolls down to daily case data table, 3 table expands, 4 sound plays if first data row of table contains yesterday's date. Repeat steps 1 through 3 until step 4 occurs.

Comment: Once the alert plays, I'm done checking for the day. I can add the new figures to our models at that point, and then tomorrow I will check again.

Comment: The code looks outstanding. A couple questions, do I paste this code into the RPA source view or does it require something called Pycharm? And what is 'd:\Python-Buch\RealPython\chromedriver.exe'? It looks like something I may not have access to.

Comment: That's Python code. So you would need a Python environment tu run the code. Pycharm oder Visual Studio Code as the IDE would be good choice. For automating the browser you'll need a so called driver. On my Windows machine for chrome the exe is chromedriver.exe which has to be downloaded. The path to that exe will be different on your machine depending on where you save the file. Automating the browser needs a bit work in setting up the environment when you cannot use an API or just parse the source code of the webpage.